# Combinations of Discussion Group

Tags: permutations, combinations

There are 18 couples that need to be split into groups of 6 individuals for discussion. What is the number of ways that this can be done given that no couples are to be in the same group.

Not sure how to begin thinking about this question,  I think I will be largely overcounting or undercounting the combinations

Comment: I got this: $\frac{2^n n!}{m\times m!\times (n/m)!}$, where $n=18$, $m=6$

Comment: how? could you explain your logic so i could try to understand please?

Comment: Groups of $6$ couples or $6$ individuals?

Comment: @barakmanos 6 individuals! sorry just changed it

Comment: In which way is this question related to permutations?

Comment: @celtschk sorry, now that i think about it, its more of a combination than a permutation

Comment: @ItsImpulse, mm.. sorry, that wasn't true. But if you allow couples in one group, you'll get $\frac{n!}{m!(n/m)!}$, where $n=36, m=6$